# where does the build log go when building castle project with nant?

Tags: build-automation, nant, castle

I am trying to build castle project using nant and get output ending in the following:

```
                common.compile-dll:

                      [csc] Compiling 92 files to 'C:\code\OSS\castle\build\net-3.5\release\Castle.Core.dll'.
                      [csc] error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Core.dll' could not be found
                      [csc] error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll' could not be found
                      [csc] error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Data.Linq.dll' could not be found
                      [csc] error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.ServiceModel.Web.dll' could not be found
                      [csc] error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll' could not be found
                      [csc] error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Web.Extensions.dll' could not be found
                      [csc] error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Xml.Linq.dll' could not be found

                BUILD FAILED

                C:\code\OSS\castle\common-project.xml(127,5):
                External Program Failed: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe (return code was 1)

                Total time: 1.1 seconds.


    BUILD FAILED

    Nested build failed.  Refer to build log for exact reason.
```

Now maybe I could figure this out or at least have a more legitimate question to ask if I knew the location of the build log, where does it typically go?  Adding the -l option to the nant command results in a log containing the exact same message as got output to screen.  Anyone have any idea?

(Interestingly this is an exact duplicate of a question that was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829907/) and deleted with no response)

Comment: weird...I lined the google cache of the previously asked question but its not showing up.  I wonder if that's by design

Answer (score 0):

your particular error seems related to nant working with wrong target framework (didn't detect/use net-3.5), try downloading last version of nant to fix the problem.

**note: castle project migrated github:**

- each core projects are now separated and migrated to **[github.com/castleproject](http://github.com/castleproject/)**
- build system is now msbuild

---

some answers to your questions:

> where does it typically go?

- build log goes to console output or where console output is redirected
- build output goes to ~/build/.NETFramework-v3.5/Release or Debug folder (I misread the which output part of your question)

> Adding the -l option to the nant command results in a log containing the exact same message as got output to screen. Anyone have any idea?

generaly with nant, you could pass the verbose argument for more diagnostics, if you want tp output the console to a file, simply suffix with > filename.txt

`nant -v ...  > verboseoutput.txt`